# How to do search in eloquent for inner tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to do filter in laravel eloquent for the inner tables, i have 3 tables, discover, category and subcategory, discover have category and subcategory id, if someone try to filter with any text name, i want to filter from all that 3 tables, i am not able to find, how to filter from category and subcategory table, here is my code, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

```
$discover = Discover::with(['category','subcategory'])->where('status','1')->where('name','like',"%{$searchString}%")->orWhere('description','like',"%{$searchString}%")->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: A [Laravel Eloquent scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes) might help with that. You add a scope to your model, which just allows any subquery you want. See documentation linked or search the internet for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you can constrain eager loading in this way:

```
Discover::with([
'category' => function($query){
          return $query->where('name','your-category-name'); 
       }
])->whereHas('category', function($query) {
          return $query->where('name','your-category-name'); 
       });
```

the same applies for other relationships. Further info can be found on the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Comment: but it doesn't filter if discovery table has no matching string

Comment: it should show parent table data, if child table has record in that

Comment: i updated the answer, you have to use whereHas too for that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this If you want to filter from child table also

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$discover = Discover::where('status', '1')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$searchString%")
    ->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use ($searchString) {
        return $query->where('name','LIKE', "%$searchString%");
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

has `whereHas` Or `WhereRelation` relation
if you need `OrderBY` on relation tables
then you need to do `join`